# ng-expression for accepting only numbers of max-length 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What should be correct ng-expression for `Numeric Input` of `max-length 10`
I have tried the basic `HTML` pattern i.e `\d{1,10}`
But it's Not working.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"` along with `ng-maxlength="10"`.